# What is a difference in Java between class B<T> extends A<T> and class B<T> extends A

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

What is the difference between:

```
// 1
class A<T>
class B<T> extends A
```

and

```
// 2
class A<T>
class B<T> extends A<T>
```

Is 1 related to the *Raw Types* like:

```
List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

whereas 2 is a preferred form
?

Comment: Don't assume that the fact both classes have a single type variable called `T` means that Java knows "this T is the same as that T". What if it were `class B<S> extends A`? Or `class B<S, T, U> extends A`? What do you think T would then be for A?

Comment: Thank you for the response. What I understand also from @Donat answer, those `T`s are completely not related, so `A` is not aware of any type parameter in `B`, and hence (correct me if I am wrong) `A` is a raw type, it holds `Object` internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one extends the raw type. There is no way then in `B` to say what type `T` in class `A` should be. `T` in `A` and `T` in `B` are unrelated.

The second one extends `A<T>`. So `T` in `A` and `T` in `B` refer to the same type.